# Why does this perl DateTime math produce unexpected results?

Tags: perl, datetime, time

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;

$a = DateTime->new(year=>1952,month=>10,day=>21);
$b = DateTime->new(year=>2015,month=>10,day=>31);

$dif = $b-$a;

print $dif->years() ." ". $dif->months() ." ". $dif->days();
# result: 63 0 3
```

Where does it get the 3 days from? My expectation is 63 0 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DateTime;

$a = DateTime->new(year=>1952,month=>11,day=>1);
$b = DateTime->new(year=>2015,month=>10,day=>31);

$dif = $b-$a;

print $dif->years() ." ". $dif->months() ." ". $dif->days();
# result 62 11 2
```

My expectation for this one is 62 11 31 or so.

I am trying to do some basic date of birth to age math. The month and year seem to work as I expect but the day seems unpredictable. I have read the CPAN documentation but I still do not understand.

Comment: Note off topic: it's better not to use the variables $a and $b, cuz they are special in perl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$dif->years`, `$diff->months` and in particular `$diff->days` do not do what you expect. From the [DateTime::Duration documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration#dur-years-dur-months-dur-weeks-dur-days-dur-hours-dur-minutes-dur-seconds-dur-nanoseconds)...

> These methods return numbers indicating how many of the given unit the
>       object represents, after having done a conversion to any larger units. For
>       example, ***days are first converted to weeks, and then the remainder is
>       returned***. These numbers are always positive.
>
> Here's what each method returns:
>
> ```
> $dur->years()       == abs( $dur->in_units('years') )
> $dur->months()      == abs( ( $dur->in_units( 'months', 'years' ) )[0] )
> $dur->weeks()       == abs( $dur->in_units( 'weeks' ) )
> $dur->days()        == abs( ( $dur->in_units( 'days', 'weeks' ) )[0] )
> ```

If you find this confusing, so do I.

What you want is [`in_units`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Duration#dur-in_units).

```
# 63 0 10
say join " ", $dif->in_units('years', 'months', 'days');
```

Comment: Interesting. So the default assumption in the package is that number of weeks are of interest. The default results for days is `mod 7` of what would normally be expected.

Comment: Excellent answer. I really appreciate you bolding the relevant documentation as well.

Comment: @JeffY Yeah, DateTime likes fixed length units. The issues of date math are covered in [How DateTime Math Works](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Datetime-Subtraction). Calendar math is complicated.

Comment: @FletcherMoore Thanks. :) I only recently discovered you can do that.